# (FlutterSplashPackageError)Execution failed for task ':flutter_native_splash:parseDebugLocalResources'. ( Android flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, compiler-errors, package

I installed the flutter_naitive_splash package i ran the `flutter pub get` and i ran into no problems when i ran dart run `flutter_native_splash:create` in the command line it was all fine the problem occurred when I ran `Flutter run`

[image: here is the errors:]
flutter plugins[image]

[image: Gradle build:]

[image: Gradle settings:]

it said something about Gradle tried updating and said i was up to date but the last version is V8.4 it was confusing i just downloaded flutter 2 days ago and tried this splash package to inset an image before running the home page
the dependencies work just fine but when I just  installed the package the `flutter run` won't work
can you please help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Goto your flutter root project and delete below file

1. .dart tool
2. Build file
3. Android >.gradle
4. ..flutter-plugins
5. .flutter-plugins-dependencies
6. pubspec.lock
7. Flutter clean
8. Flutter pub get
9. Flutter run

If the problem is not solve then you have to check your flutter and dart version

Better solution is to load splash screen manually not to use any package.

Comment: 1- .dart too
2- Build file
3- Android >.gradle
4- ..flutter-plugins
5- .flutter-plugins-dependencies
6- pubspec.lock
//////////////////////////
delete all of those files ?why?

Comment: sometimes those file are caches version and other dependencies that's why delete all this and follow my step..those file again generated automatically